# Why is there a function in my javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code loops over an array. It is running within a casperJS script and therefore a phantomJS headless browser environment

```
socket.on('list', function(data){
                console.log("Message", JSON.stringify(data)); //no func def in this data
                var localMatchStore= [];
                for (var i in data.matches) {
                   localMatchStore.push(data.matches[i]);
                }
                console.log(localMatchStore);

            });
```

This returns the data I expect but also a function definition as the last item in the array. Why is this?

```
0580:MS101:2014,0580:MS127:2014,0580:MS128:2014,0901:LS162:2014,function () {
        for(var i=0,sum=0;i<this.length;sum+=this[i++]);
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `hasOwnProperty()` with your `for..in`. That loop construct can include members of the object that are *inherited* through the prototype chain. `hasOwnProperty()` ensures that the property is a direct member.

```
socket.on('list', function(data){
    console.log("Message", JSON.stringify(data)); //no func def in this data

    var localMatchStore= [];

    for (var i in data.matches) {
        if (data.matches.hasOwnProperty(i)) localMatchStore.push(data.matches[i]);
    }

    console.log(localMatchStore);

});
```

For a more in-depth discussion of this function see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) on MDN.